# The requested resource is not available with tomcat8 deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat8

Every time i m getting msg "The requested resource is not available". i created a maven project in spring framework. its building successfully but when i want to execute with tomcate7 or tomcate8 , its giving same error. java version is 1.8.
its silly a sample code, i don't know why i m getting this error.

here are code snippet :

1.POM XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>AquaEPP</groupId>
        <artifactId>AquaEPP</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <name>AquaEPP</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                <version>${cglib.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Servlet Spec -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.14</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>springsource-milestones</id>
                <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <build>
            <finalName>AquaEPP</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

2. WEB.XML

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
           <display-name>AquaEPP</display-name>
           <welcome-file-list>
           <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
         </welcome-file-list>
           <context-param>
               <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
               <param-value>
                   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
               </param-value>
           </context-param>
           <listener>
               <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
           </listener>

           <servlet>
               <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
               <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
               <init-param>
                   <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
                   <param-value>
                       org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
                   </param-value>
               </init-param>
               <init-param>
                   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                   <param-value>com.exp.aqua</param-value>
               </init-param>
               <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
           </servlet>
           <servlet-mapping>
               <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
               <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
           </servlet-mapping>

           <session-config>
               <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
           </session-config>
       </web-app>
   ```

3.controller class

```
        package com.exp.aqua.controller;

        import java.io.IOException;

        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

        @Controller
        public class HomeController {

            @RequestMapping(value="/home")
            public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
                return new ModelAndView("home");
            }
        }
```

4.MvcConfiguration class

```
            package com.exp.aqua.config;

            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

            @Configuration
            @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.exp.aqua")
            @EnableWebMvc
            public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

                @Bean
                public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
                    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
                    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
                    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
                    return resolver;
                }

                @Override
                public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
                }


            }
```

5.index.jsp

```
            <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Spring Demo</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <br>
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <h2>
                        Hey You..!! This is your 1st Spring MCV Tutorial..<br> <br>
                    </h2>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="home.jsp">Click here to See Welcome Message... </a>(to
                        check Spring MVC Controller... @RequestMapping("/welcome"))
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

6. home.jsp

   ```
           <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
           <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

           <html>
               <head>
                   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                   <title>Home</title>
               </head>
               <body>
                   <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                   <p>This is the homepage!</p>
               </body>
           </html>
   ```

Comment: You must give more details about your execution. How are you invoking the service?

Comment: first i built the project with maven using clean install,than added the tomcat server in eclipse,tried to run with tomcat server, but it gave 404 no resource found. I did below quick fix , but no help.  :                                        1. changed the location of tomcat server, 2. tried with tomcat 7 also 3. cleaned .m2 dir.... etc

Comment: you run your tomcat server, but what endpoint are you calling to?

Comment: localhost:8080/projname or localhost:8080/projname/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with your tomcat, that works for me:

1.- Right click on your project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies

2.- In your `MvcConfiguration` the basePackages of your `@ComponentScan` must be `com.exp.aqua.controller`.

3.- In your `index.jsp` remove the `.jsp` extension in the `href` attribute: `<a href="home">`

Finally, remember your `index.jsp` must be in the `WebContent` folder and `home.jsp` in `views`.

[image]

Comment: i already did 1st one , no help. For 2nd one , this structure is auto generated by maven and spring dependency. Any way working fine without maven. May be issue with maven .

Comment: But have you tried to imlement my full solution?? That could allow you to have the application working keeping maven, that I suppose it's your aim